# Android: how to use SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() to show second one by one?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk

I am using the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to display the time.

But now I want to show the seconds one-by-one to be increase based on the `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` time.
And yes I must use the thred.

So how to do it ?

I have tried it with this thread:

```
// Start lengthy operation in a background thread
progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        while (mProgressStatus < 1000) {
            mProgressStatus = ((int) (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() / 10));
            // Update the progress bar
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {   
                    // try {
                    //  // progressThread.sleep(1000);
                    // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                    // }
                    // progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    System.out.println("SECOND is :" + mProgressStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So what should I change in this thread to get seconds one by one to be increased ??

Please help me for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) class. You can bind it to `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` using `setBase()`. Another way could be if you use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) inside an Activity and using the [sendEmptyMessageDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) method with value 1000 to update your timer.

Comment: May be it possible. Will you please explain in more detail for my case ? Actually i have use chronometer and based on the Chronometer time, i want to show the progressbar for specific minimum and Maximum Value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a second thread to get the elapsed time (as you have done) then you MUST employ some method to notify your Activity's main thread that the canvas must be re-painted, as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-view) and in [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)

You could also employ a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) which has been instantiated in your Activities Main thread. From your second thread (which gets the system time) you send a [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) which contains the system time to the Handler. Because the Handler runs in the Main thread it is safe to alter Views from here. I would doubt that this is an accurate way of displaying system time on Android i.e. I would think there's a better way.